# How to clear Recent Places in MacOS Ventura 13.3.1?

Tags: macos, terminal, ventura

I have tried this in Terminal:

```
defaults delete -g NSNavRecentPlaces
```

but this error message happens:

> 2023-05-04 19:04:26.300 defaults[1160:46791]

> Domain (kCFPreferencesAnyApplication) not found. Defaults have not been
> changed.

How can I clear Recent Places via Terminal in MacOS Ventura 13.3.1 on a 2020 MacBook Pro - this issues never happened on previous iterations of Mac OSX I used?

Monterey did not have this issue.

If you could help this is appreciated.

Comment: What is the last "previous iteration" of macOS you've used?  I can find it in Sierra, but not Big Sur any more - has it been a while?

Comment: Do you have a special application in mind, for which you want to delete the recent folders?  E.g. `defaults delete com.apple.Finder FXRecentFolders`

Comment: Monterey was the previous version used. It's for when I do open file via Finder or Firefox.

Comment: "...when I do open file via Finder".  You may also want to expand on this further, since the normal "Open" menu opens a selected file straight away, without an open and save panel.  Only "Open with...> Other" offers the panel as far as I can see.

Answer (score 2):

To clear "Recent Places" in the open and save panels, run...

```
defaults delete com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService NSNavRecentPlaces
```

As already mentioned in the comments,...

```
defaults delete com.apple.Finder FXRecentFolders
```

...clears Finder's "**Go** > **Recent Folders**" menu, since Finder does not offer an openAndSave panel with the "**File** > **Open**" menu (<kbd>command</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>), unlike applications like Safari, or Firefox, etc.

Those entries have long existed before Monterey though (I'm seeing it here on Big Sur).

PS. `defaults` can easily be searched - see `man defaults` for details:

> ```
>  find word    Searches for word in the domain names, keys, and values of the user's defaults, and prints out a list of matches.
> ```

e.g. in your case:

```
defaults find NSNavRecentPlaces
```