File picker forgets last location (always uses home folder) and can’t access recent folders
In all apps, when I summon the “File, Open” dialog (file selector, file picker), it is supposed to open with the last location accessed. But instead, it is always opening at my home folder. Also, any clicks of “Recent Places” fail (instead of opening the clicked directory, they just open the home folder).
This wastes a lot of time when I need to open (or upload) multiple files, and it frustrates me every day.
Apple had me run many tests for several hours a day over several months, and they eventually gave up and said to wipe my Mac, reinstall macOS, and rebuild my machine manually from scratch. This week I invested five full-time days doing so, and just as I was nearly finished doing so, the bug has now randomly reappeared.
MacBook Pro running macOS 14.5 Sonoma. Bug does not occur when I create a new user admin account.
In searching the web, I see other people complaining about this, but I do not find a solution. Any help, ideas?

Default Folder X is something that lets you change all sorts of defaults not normally accessible in macOS. This includes the feature you want. Using an app to work around an issue with your current setup may not be preferable but it also may be better than wiping your drive and starting over.

First of all, each app remembers its own last location, e.g. if I open/save a file in TextEdit, that does not affect Safari's open panel.
Each app saves the Last location used in its Preference file, usually com.company.appname.plist, using the key    NSNavLastRootDirectory
Consequently, this is entirely a user issue and wiping and reinstalling the OS is completely unnecessary. (Indeed, it's almost always unnecessary.)
So the first thing I would do is check the plist files of a few apps, and see what the value of that key is. The location is now a little bit complicated: the file for TextEdit, for example is at:
~/Library/Containers/com.apple.TextEdit/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.TextEdit.plist

(where ~ is your User account home.)
For Safari, the file is at:
~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Safari/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist

... and so on. In the Finder, you might see just Safari as the subfolder of Containers, rather than com.apple.safari.
You could set the last location in the Terminal, with the command:
defaults write  com.apple.TextEdit NSNavLastRootDirectory "~/Desktop"

It's possible that inserting a value in this way will get things working properly again.
Alternatively, you mention that Recent Places doesn't work either. It's possible that the Recent Places list is corrupt, which is having some knock-on effect for the dialog as a whole.
You could try clearing the Recent Places list -- System Settings > Control Center > Recent documents (at the very bottom). Set it to "None".
There may be a way to do this programmatically.

"Recent Places" is found in an Open and Save Panel's preferences: see https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/459577/49869

If I launch TextEdit.app, open a file, begin to open another file and find the bug, close the file and quit the app, and look in ~/Library/Containers/, I see no com.apple.TextEdit folder. I do see in the Containers folder a TextEdit folder, which has a Containers.plist file and a Data folder. If I run your command, the bug is not changed. Also if I delete the contents of the TextEdit folder, the bug is not changed. If I change the Recent Places amount in Syst Prefs, the bug is not changed. If I change the RA amount in SP and reboot, the bug is not changed, and the RA sets itself to none.

Yes, the name inside Container might just be "TextEdit" instead of the identifier. I would try deleting the Recent Places data in Redarm's link in the comment above.

If I run in Terminal the two commands that you link, defaults delete com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService NSNavRecentPlaces and defaults delete com.apple.Finder FXRecentFolders, and I reboot my Mac, the bug still exists.

@2540625 There's definitely something in your user Library that's got's corrupted, so you'll have to try being more large-scale. Delete the entire com.apple.finder.plist and of the others we've mentioned. You can always restore them from your backup if it doesn't work. You'll need to log out and back in to see the change.

There is no “com.apple.finder.plist” (and no “com.apple.finder.[anything]”, and no “Finder”) in ~/Library/Containers.

@2540625 It's in ~/Library/Preferences.

If I quit all apps and trash ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder, it immediately respawns. If I then reboot and test the bug, it still exists.

@2540625 Hmm. Very weird. Have you tested whether the behaviour happens in a brand new user account? That would at least definitively prove it's a user account issue. If it is, then it's got to be something in the Library, so usual practice is to remove half the files and test; then test the other half, and divide into halves again and again. Also, you haven't said what OS version it is, or what the hardware is.

The issue does not occur in a newly created user on my account. MacBook Pro running macOS 14.5. Deleting half the contents of my user library sounds dangerous?

@2540625 Well, the brand new user account will have nothing in its Library. Start with the contents of the Preferences subfolder. At worst, you will lose some preferences, settings, etc. If you move them, and then replace them if there's no change, you will only be in a "wrong state" temporarily.
